# How to download Azure migrate dependency diagrams?

Tags: azure, migrate, infrastructure

I am trying to download Azure Migrate dependency diagrams. I tried to  take screenshots but some diagrams are very big to fit on the screen. So is there any way to actually download the dependency diagrams.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not available today and it is on our backlog. For now, you would have to capture screenshots.

Reach out to me @sadahmed at Microsoft dot com and reference this link and I shall help you connect with the PM working on this feature who would be glad to understand your requirement and help with the same.

Comment: Thanks, Sadiqh hope I'll get some solution for this.